# Can't iterate over array in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need to add a new column with a (ordinal) number after the last column in my table.

Both input and output files are .CSV tables.

Incoming table has more then 500 000 lines (rows) of data and 7 columns, e.g. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2u68fxrkttv4gq/incoming_data.csv?dl=0

Incoming CSV table (this is just an example, so "|" and "-" are here for the sake of clarity):

```
| id     | Name |
-----------------
| 1      | Foo  |
| 1      | Foo  |
| 1      | Foo  |
| 4242   | Baz  |
| 4242   | Baz  |
| 4242   | Baz  |
| 4242   | Baz  |
| 702131 | Xyz  |
| 702131 | Xyz  |
| 702131 | Xyz  |
| 702131 | Xyz  |
```

Result CSV (this is just an example, so "|" and "-" are here for the sake of clarity):

```
| id     | Name |        |
--------------------------
| 1      | Foo  | 1      |
| 1      | Foo  | 2      |
| 1      | Foo  | 3      |
| 4242   | Baz  | 1      |
| 4242   | Baz  | 2      |
| 4242   | Baz  | 3      |
| 4242   | Baz  | 4      |
| 702131 | Xyz  | 1      |
| 702131 | Xyz  | 2      |
| 702131 | Xyz  | 3      |
| 702131 | Xyz  | 4      |
```

First column is ID, so I've tried to group all lines with the same ID and iterate over them. Script (I don't know bash scripting, to be honest):

```
FILE=$PWD/$1
# Delete header and extract IDs and delete non-unique values. Also change \n to ♥, because awk doesn't properly work with it.
IDS_ARRAY=$(awk -v FS="|" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="\"") inQ=!inQ; ORS=(inQ?"♥":"\n") }1' $FILE | awk -F'|' '{if (NR!=1) {print $1}}' | awk '!seen[$0]++')

for id in $IDS_ARRAY; do
  # Group $FILE by $id from $IDS_ARRAY.    
  cat $FILE | grep $id >> temp_mail_group.csv
  ROW_GROUP=$PWD/temp_mail_group.csv

  # Add a number after each row.
  # NF+1 — add a column after last existing.
  awk -F'|' '{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS="|", $ROW_GROUP >> "numbered_mails_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).csv"
  rm -f $PWD/temp_mail_group.csv
done
```

Right now this script works almost like I want to, except that it thinks that (for example) ID 2834 and 772834 are the same.

*UPD: Although I marked one answer as approved it does not assign correct values to some groups of records with the same ID (right now I don't see a pattern).*

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to achieve by your script. Would you mind posting the expected output for the sample table?

Comment: What if you just say `awk '{print $1, $2, ++a[$1]}' file`?

Comment: When you want to loopthrough our output, why not skip the array:
`awk xxxx | while read id; do ...`

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you! It helped me a lot.

BTW, $1, $2, $3... — numbers of columns? I'm trying to understand this magic.

Comment: Yes! With `$n` you access to the column `n`. As default, he columns are based on space. But of course you can change it: `awk -F"\t" '{print $2}' file` will print the second field of a tab separated file.

Comment: Post the correct input and output, if they are CSVs post CSVs

Comment: wrt `"|" and "-" are here for the sake of clarity` - Posting a table that shows "|" and "-" that do not actually exist in your real files in absolutely no way improves the clarity of your question. How would you feel if you spent hours telling someone how to jump-start their car and then they said "thanks, it's actually a horse, I just said it was a car for clarity"?

Comment: @Jidder Done: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2u68fxrkttv4gq/incoming_data.csv?dl=0 I want to add ordinal numbers to the column 'Level'.

Answer (score 3):

You can do everything in a single script:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|";}
/^-/ {print; next;}
$2 ~ /\s*id\s*/ {print $0,""; next;}
 {print "", $2, $3, ++a[$2];}
'
```

`$1` is the empty field before the first `|` in the input. I use an empty output column `""` to get the leading `|`.

The trick is `++a[$2]` which takes the second field in each row (= the ID column) and looks for it in the associative array `a`. If there is no entry, the result is `0`. By pre-incrementing, we start with `1` and add `1` every time the ID reappears.

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific above so no need to specify gawk. It won't provide the required output spacing and `|` symbols though.

Comment: @EdMorton: I tend to avoid `awk` because it has so many limitations and oddities.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that statement. awk is THE right tool for UNIX text manipulation because anything else has limitations and oddities while awk doesn't because, in the UNIX spirit, it was designed to do one thing and do it well and that one thing is text manipulation. If you can give an example of something you perceive as a limitation or oddity I can clear up that misconception for you.

Comment: Ed, `gawk` is the successor for `awk`. While `awk` might be available on many Unix systems, each vendor created their own version so they all behave slightly different. On top of that, they lack many important features. So from my 20+ year experience: Unless you know exactly what you're doing or you can't install `gawk` for some reason (company policy), stay away from pure POSIX `awk`. It's just not worth the time.

Comment: From my 30+ years experience: any modern awk (e.g. BSD awk, POSIX awk, nawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, etc.) is fine most of the time, gawk just has some very useful additional features that make it highly preferable to have available. I understand where you're coming from now though - you weren't saying "avoid awk" you were saying "avoid non-gawk". I thought you were advocating some crazy shell+sed loop or similar. I do agree that everyone should try to use gawk as their first choice of awk but in a trivial case like this any modern awk has all the functionality you need.

Answer (score 2):

An awk way

Without considering the dotted line being extended.

```
awk 'NR>2{$0=$0 (++a[$2])"|"}1' file
```

#### output

```
| id | Name |
-------------
| 1  | Foo  |1|
| 1  | Foo  |2|
| 1  | Foo  |3|
| 42 | Baz  |1|
| 42 | Baz  |2|
| 42 | Baz  |3|
| 42 | Baz  |4|
| 70 | Xyz  |1|
| 70 | Xyz  |2|
| 70 | Xyz  |3|
| 70 | Xyz  |4|
```

Comment: Thank you for the shortest and simplest answer. But you forgot the space after the -v :)

Comment: @EvgenyM. to be clear, this answer is shortest and simplest because it doesn't produce the output you asked for. There are even shorter and simpler answers than this possible that also would not produce the output you asked for. It's important when asking questions to correctly state the desired output so you don't waste several people's time trying to help you and you get the best solution for whatever it is you actually want to do.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for your time and help. Next time I will try to express myself more accurately. Sorry.

Comment: @EdMorton whats unnecessary ?

Comment: setting FS, setting OFS, populating $0 and so causing re-splitting of the record into fields. All you need is a single print statement: `awk '{print $0 (NR>2 ? ++a[$2] "|" : "")}' file`.

Comment: @edmorton thats longer though ? Also i had removed the fs ofs

Comment: @EdMorton Also the fields aren't split or else you would need the FS and OFS, changing $0 does not require an field splitting.

Comment: There's 2 separate discussions here: 1) the briefest script that will produce output other than asked for but which may also be acceptable, and 2) what is unnecessary in the above answer. My most recent comment is in response to your question `whats unnecessary?` and so addresses "2" (yes I see you did remove some of the unnecessary operations) but is not intended to address "1". To address "1" `{print $0, ++a[$2]}` would produce output other than requested but also possibly acceptable.

Comment: Assigning to `$0` does force field-splitting, it does not force the record to be re-constructed as assigning to a field would do. Both use `FS`, only the latter uses `OFS`. Try `echo "a b" | awk '{$0="c d"; print $1}'` and you'll find the output is `c`, not `a`.

Comment: @EdMorton Both FS and OFS would be needed for correct output, also `{print $0, ++a[$2]}` would print a number on the title line(s).

Comment: @EdMorton To address the edit to your comment The line is split when you call `$1` not when you assign `$0`.

Comment: @Jidder not sure what you mean by `Both FS and OFS would be needed for correct output` and yes that's exactly correct that it would print a number at the end of the title lines - it's something that's also not as requested (just like not providing the header for the 3rd column and not extending the `-`s) but possibly just as acceptable. We have no idea what the "correct output" is, all we know is that it's NOT what was requested.

Comment: No, assigning to $0 does the split. Try changing the number of fields and printing NF. From the POSIX standard: `Assigning to $0 shall reset the values of all other fields and the NF built-in variable.`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html

Comment: @EdMorton Without looking through the source code i can't really argue anymore and its a pretty pointless argument anyway, so you win, my answer sucks.

Comment: Your answer's fine, but if the OP just told us what they really want there's other answers (s)he should consider too.

Comment: @EdMorton I've improved my question. You were right, the Jidder's answer doesn't do what I want (but failed to describe properly).

Comment: Your input and desired output are actually CSV files??? I personally am not going to bother modifying my answer as that's absolutely ridiculous that you'd write your question using one format of input/output when you really want something completely different and so waste the time of everyone trying to help you. The answer for CSV is completely trivial so I'm sure you'll get an answer but IMHO you should accept Jidder's answer again since he, like the rest of us, put effort into answering your question and ask a new question with your ACTUAL input/output, not some completely different format.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text - don't disappoint them :-).

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ w = 8 }
{
    if (NR==1) {
        val = sprintf("%*s|",w,"")
    }
    else if (NR==2) {
        val = sprintf("%*s",w+1,"")
        gsub(/ /,"-",val)
    }
    else {
        val = sprintf(" %-*s|",w-1,++cnt[$2])
    }
    print $0 val
}
' file
| id | Name |        |
----------------------
| 1  | Foo  | 1      |
| 1  | Foo  | 2      |
| 1  | Foo  | 3      |
| 42 | Baz  | 1      |
| 42 | Baz  | 2      |
| 42 | Baz  | 3      |
| 42 | Baz  | 4      |
| 70 | Xyz  | 1      |
| 70 | Xyz  | 2      |
| 70 | Xyz  | 3      |
| 70 | Xyz  | 4      |
```

Comment: I was going to do something similar but won't the formatting mess up if there are two digit numbers ?Tried it two digit is fine, but three digit messes it up, doesn't look like OP's data would go that high though so +1 :)

Comment: It would have so I modified it. The requested alignment in the added column isn't clear but it should be clear that you just need to tweak the last `sprintf` as desired.

Comment: Thanks, but @Jidder's answer is shorter :)

Comment: @EvgenyM. yes, it is shorter because it doesn't produce the output you asked for. If you would like a different script that is briefer still and also doesn't do what you asked for, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with pure Bash:

```
inputfile=$1

prev_id=
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    printf '%s' "$line"

    IFS=$'| \t\n' read t1 id name t2 <<<"$line"

    if [[ $line == -* ]] ; then
        printf '%s\n' '---------'
    elif [[ $id == 'id' ]] ; then
        printf ' Number |\n'
    else
        if [[ $id != "$prev_id" ]] ; then
            id_count=0
            prev_id=$id
        fi

        printf '%2d      |\n' "$(( ++id_count ))"
    fi
done <"$inputfile"
```

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765 written by the shell expert who discovered the shellshock bug.

Comment: @EdMorton, the referenced article has useful examples of bad Bash code, and bad coding practices.  It also has interesting, but debatable, opinions about the suitability of Bash for some programming tasks, particularly compared to Python and C.  If you have found any specific problems with the Bash code posted here I will try to either fix them or document them.  Note, however, that with a problem like this, where both the input and the output are poorly specified, it's not worthwhile to put a lot of effort into ruggedizing the code.

Comment: there may or may not be problems with it, as you say all things considered it's not worth putting effort into inspecting it.